# Why do we use String docType in java? also tell me their advantages?

Tags: java, html

I'm a beginner in servlet now I found that we would have to use in Java for servlet programming like this:

```
String docType =
                "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
                        "transitional//en\">\n";
```

Now I want to know what's the benefit of that to use into programming? And also tell me that using of their advantages...

here is my program that I'm using this.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        String title="This is just a title and nothing except that..";
        String docType =
                "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
                        "transitional//en\">\n";

        out.println(docType+
        "<html>"+
        "<head><title>"+
        title+
        "</title></head>"+
        "<body>"+
        "<h1 align='center'>"
        +title+
        "</h1>"+
        "<ul>"+
        "<li>"+
        "<b>First name: </b>"+
        request.getParameter("first_name")+"<br>"+
        "<b>Last name: </b>"+
        request.getParameter("last_name")+
        "</li>"+
        "</ul>"+
        "</body>"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just HTML that is echoed. This has *nothing* to do with Java.

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with MySQL or Servlets either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web pages are written in [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML). At the top of an HTML page, there should be a [document type declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Document_type_declaration), that describes exactly which variant of HTML is used (unfortunately, because of historical reasons, there are different variants / versions of HTML being used around the web).

A [servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) is a software component that runs inside a servlet container. The servlet container receives HTTP requests from a browser and calls the servlets that are deployed in it to handle these requests. The servlet produces output to be sent back to whoever made the request (usually a web browser). The output is often in HTML.

So, the servlet needs to output the doctype because that's just part of the HTML page that it produces.